# How can I compile Evince3 on Windows using msys2 from Evince3 Source Codes?

Tags: windows, gcc, compilation, gtk, msys2

Evince3 Source Code link = http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/evince/3.26/

I downloaded the Evince3 pdf reader program source code from the above link. and installed msys2 with gcc and gtk3 librares. Evince3 created using gtk3 module in C. but I don't know how to compile source code of Evince3 for using this program on Windows. Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious to learn how to build Gtk apps on windows, so I did it myself, and it took me around one hour.

I followed this guide, [https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows.](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/08/01/how-to-build-your-gtk-application-on-windows/)

Note that the author used `gedit` as example. To install `evince`, you need to download three files from this directory(get 32 or 64 version of install file), https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-evince.

Modify `pkgver` to `3.26.0` and `sha256sum` to the hash value in `evince-3.26.0.sha256sum` in `PKGBUILD` file, and follow the rest of instructions.

Other way: It's also possible to install pre-built package from mysys2 repo with compiling the source code. Open the msys2 console and give the following command to install Evince.

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-evince`

Comment: I edited your answer for adding other option to install Evince. thanks. I installed Evince with only one command using msys2 console: `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-evince`